# In Emacs how to switch to other buffer?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

The problem is following: I want to automate the way my emacs starts.
It has to be split in two buffers and the slime-repl has to be started in the smallest (bottom) buffer. Plus, I want my file to be opened in the bigger (upper) buffer.
In my .emacs there are lines:

```
(slime)
...
(split-window-vertically -6)
(switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))
(find-file "g:/Private/pa/pa2.lsp")
```

SLIME opens o.k. in the bottom buffer, but the file is opened in one of the background buffers, while I want it to be in front.

How to fix this?

Comment: You should probably edit the subject line of this question to summarise your particular problem. See the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `switch-to-buffer`, use function `pop-to-buffer`.

> `(pop-to-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME &optional OTHER-WINDOW NORECORD)`
>
> Select buffer `BUFFER-OR-NAME` in some window, preferably a different one.

Answer (score 1):

You can look to the function set-window-configuration...

But for slime you can use following functions - slime-complete-maybe-save-window-configuration & slime-complete-restore-window-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(other-window 1)
(find-file "g:/Private/pa/pa2.lsp")
```

instead of your last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
(ido-mode 1)
```

to your .emacs, and enjoy the result :)